# RegEx to redirect certain URL path

Tags: .net, regex, urlrewriter.net

I am trying to create a rule that redirects /parent/special/{anything} to /parent/{anything}. In other words to remove the "special" from the URL if it is there after "parent". This is for a .NET application, more specifically for http://urlrewriter.net. Can someone help with this?

Comment: On which language are you developing on?

Comment: ...match "/parent/special/" and replace it with "/parent/"? so no regex needed?

Comment: A rule in what? You may want to provide more information about where you want to use the regex as that will affect the syntax used.

Comment: I updated the question with more details

Comment: @TruMan1 updated my answer to include {anything} after /special.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple, try this:

Redirect all requests from: `parent/special/(.*)`

to: `parent/$1`

If you're using Apache, the RewriteRule would look like this:

```
RewriteRule parent/special/(.*) parent/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a PCRE compliant language, you could use this:

```
(\/\w+\/)(?:special\/)?(.*$)
```

And replace with: `$1$2`.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/uM8rA7

If you specifically want `/parent`, just replace `\w+` with `parent`.

**Edited** to allow for anything after `/special`.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex:

```
(\/\w+\/)special\/
```

Would capture the `/parent/` path only if it's followed by `special`.

[Check it here](http://regex101.com/r/sZ2tT9)

Comment: How would I add what was after "special" back to the URL?

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that on your question. Go with @remus approach then.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
sed -i 's/parent\/special/parent/g' file.txt
```